# xlwt use Hyperlink with variable

Tags: python, xlwt

I would like to use xlwt to generate hyperlink in particular cell. I tried to put following in formula, it's fine:

```
Hyperlink("http://www.google.com";"Link")
```

But when I define `X='"http://www.google.com"'` (Note the single quote outside of double quote)
and then:
`Hyperlink(X;"Link")`
It won't work.

Basically, I want to put a variable `X`, which could be different when the program runs, into `Hyperlink()`. Any idea to fix this problem would be appreciated!

Comment: hey Tom i would like to see the code please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this construct

```
click='"http://www.google.com"'
wsheet.write(j,8,xlwt.Formula('HYPERLINK(%s;"Link")' % click))
```

or, easier to read and maintain:

```
click='http://www.google.com'
wsheet.write(j,8,xlwt.Formula('HYPERLINK("%s";"Link")' % click))
```

For details of the `%` operator for string formatting, see
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: Of course `Formula` isn't a python function... it should be `xlwt.Formula(...)`.

Comment: How could the wsheet.write line be used where "Link" is a variable as well? I am getting the error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting